# How to change PHP date

Tags: php, apache

I am running Apache on CentOS. The date on CentOS is setup correct, but the date PHP is returning is 1970 I'm guessing it is something with PHP that I have to change.

How can I do this?

Comment: How are you getting the date in PHP?

Comment: Please post the code for how you're getting the date in PHP. It sounds like you're giving it an empty value for the datestamp, for instance. http://codepad.org/4LSc9q5Y

Comment: 1970 is the UNIX / POSIX time epoch. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time . January 1st, 1970 to be precise. I think it's a matter of you're doing it wrong

Comment: It seems that you are calling `date` without any argument or an empty argument. This is a kind of RTFM question.

Comment: @eyazici, You can't call php with an empty first argument, if the second was empty, it would be returning the current time in the format.  What it looks like is that hes calling the second parameter with false, null or 0.

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing in a second parameter to the `date` function that is NULL / empty?  This would mean that the date you are producing - according to the format you specify in the first parameter - would be the unix epoch date (1 January 1970).

Answer (score 0):

PHP counts time in seconds from 12:00am January 1, 1970 (as do most computer languages).

```
date('h:i:s d M Y', 0) => 12:00:00 01 Jan 1970;
date('h:i:s d M Y', null) => 12:00:00 01 Jan 1970;
date('h:i:s d M Y', false) => 12:00:00 01 Jan 1970;

date('h:i:s d M Y') => current date/time
```

See: 
http://codepad.org/rm2QCaID

Make sure that your second parameter is filled in with a valid time.